# Работа notifaction после закрытия приложения

Tags: android, время

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            addNotification1("");//метод уведомление
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000, 50000);//время через которое он будет повторятся 2 число
```

как реализовать чтобы после закрытия приложения оно продолжала работать

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `Timer` никак. Используйте `AlarmManager` как описано здесь:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html